# Override/wrap log4net to serialize objects

Tags: c#, .net-core, log4net

We have a practice of logging on entry to each method:

```cs
public void DoSomething(string someWords, bool definitely)
{
  Logger.Log.Debug(new { someWords, definitely });
  // DoSomething
}
```

This works because we built a wrapper around the default Log which calls:

`Logger.Log.Debug(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));`

Unfortunately it's breaking the logging because instead of getting the class/method/line number etc of the `Logger.Log.Debug()`, we're getting the class/method/line of the wrapper!

One idea we had was to create a simple extension method:

```cs
﻿using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace System
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string S<T>(this T o)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
        }
    }
}
```

So we can do `Logger.Log.Debug(new { someWords, definitely }.S());` but i'm not too keen.

Any better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a custom `Log4net` [`IObjectRenderer`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_ObjectRenderer_IObjectRenderer.htm) which is responsible to render the `object`/message to be logged to a `string`.

Doing so, you can use the regular logging methods - instead of helper/extension methods - ensuring that the expected class, method, line numbers, etc. appear in the output.

Note that an `IObjectRenderer` is also being used when logging an `Exception`.
Depending on your use case, you might not want that to be in `JSON` format.

```
namespace PFX
{
    public class CustomObjectRenderer : IObjectRenderer
    {
        public CustomObjectRenderer()
        { }

        public void RenderObject(RendererMap rendererMap, object obj, TextWriter writer)
        { 
            if (obj is Exception)
            {
                rendererMap.DefaultRenderer.RenderObject(rendererMap, obj, writer);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You register that `IObjectRenderer` in the `Log4net` configuration as below,
where `PFX.CustomObjectRenderer` is the namespace + name of the renderer class and `MyAssembly` is the name of the assembly.
You can register multiple renderers; here one and the same is being used to render every object as `JSON`.

```
<renderer renderingClass="PFX.CustomObjectRenderer, MyAssembly" renderedClass="System.Object" />
```

A full configuration example

```
<log4net>
  <renderer renderingClass="PFX.CustomObjectRenderer, MyAssembly" renderedClass="System.Object" />
  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file value="log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

The below call

```
log.Info(new { someWords, definitely });
```

will output

```
2022-03-24 22:48:22,865 INFO Log {"someWords":"words","definitely":true}
```

Comment: You are a legend @pfx - thank you so much, this works a treat!!!